# C# Insert Image to Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, image

I am trying to insert an image to Mysql. However, I got a problem when I try to insert I am getting System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: encoder' error. Thanks for your attention.  (X Type is BLOB in MYSQL)

```
var image = bmp;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
byte[] img= ms.ToArray();


MySqlConnection open = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User=root;Password=123456789;database=deneme1;pooling='true'; Max Pool Size = 100000");
open.Open();

MySqlCommand add = new MySqlCommand("Insert Into controller (img) VALUES (@img)", open);

add.Parameters.AddWithValue("img", img);

add.ExecuteNonQuery();
add.Dispose();
open.Close();
```

EDIT : image.Save(ms , System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

Solved.

Comment: in which line you get this error ?

Comment: image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);  @farbiondriven